# jQuery add class on scroll, but not on initial load

Tags: jquery

I have this code here that adds and removes class based on scroll position, this even works on initial load and I do not want it to, how do I prevent that?

```
jQuery(window).scroll(function () {

  var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

  console.log(scroll);

  if (scroll >= 100) {
    jQuery("#banner").addClass("sticky");
  } else if (scroll == 0) {
    jQuery("#banner").removeClass("sticky");
  }

  if (scroll > 0) {
    jQuery(".navigation-top").addClass("sticky");
  } else if (scroll == 0) {
    jQuery(".navigation-top").removeClass("sticky");
  }

});
```

The issue is on the initial load when you refresh the page and the scroll is not 0

Comment: When do you run this code? Where's the top part matching the `}):` at the end?

Comment: my bad updated my question

Comment: This should not run on page load. There must be something else you're not showing

Comment: That is alll the jquery code

Comment: I cannot reproduce this ~ http://jsfiddle.net/49twhcvo/

Comment: The issue is on the inital load when you refresh the page and the scroll is not 0

Comment: That's probably worth mentioning in your question

Comment: Yes probably.....was writing quickly

Comment: Have a boolean value set to false on document ready, and then set up an event listener to detect a scroll and set that boolean flag to true, put the code block in an if statement that checks the boolean flag.

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a boolean variable with an if statement in the scroll function to determine if the code should be run or not.

Here, we disable the code by setting variable to true onload, then on scroll we set it to false, allowing the function to execute.

```
var onload_functionDisable = true;

jQuery(window).scroll(function() {

    if (onload_functionDisable == false) {
        var scroll = jQuery(window).scrollTop();

        console.log(scroll);

        if (scroll >= 100) {
            jQuery("#banner").addClass("sticky");
        } else if (scroll == 0) {
            jQuery("#banner").removeClass("sticky");
        }

        if (scroll > 0) {
            jQuery(".navigation-top").addClass("sticky");
        } else if (scroll == 0) {
            jQuery(".navigation-top").removeClass("sticky");
        }
    }
    onload_functionDisable = false;
});
```

**Edit**
The previous code was wrong and would always run. So now have improved it by moving the `onload_functionDisable = false;` to the bottom of `scroll function`. So on load the scroll function is disabled, but as soon as it skips the scroll code, the variable is set to false, enabling the code for the next scroll event.

I have a working [simplified jsfiddle showing this.](https://jsfiddle.net/j4vm8py0/14/)

Comment: Your logic is in the wrong order. `onload_functionDisable` will **always** be `false` when it gets to `if (onload_functionDisable == false)`

Comment: I have changed my code slightly, and added a fully tested and working jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is on the inital load when you refresh the page and the scroll is not 0

Okay.. The only solution I think of is:

On load, you will force scrollTop to zero.
Then register the `scroll` event handler.

```
$(window).scrollTop(0);

$(window).scroll(function () {

  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  console.log(scroll);

  $("#banner").toggleClass("sticky", scroll >= 100 );
  $(".navigation-top").toggleClass("sticky", scroll > 0 );
});
```

The second argument is a condition that returns a true/false, in both cases.

Comment: Won't this make the page jump around? Sounds like OP wants the initial position to be maintained

Comment: Hew... This should force all new page load to be glued to top on load. @Phil: "initial position to be maintained" ? I don't think so. -> *«this even works on initial load and I do not want it to»*

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found a solution here: https://www.py4u.net/discuss/959392
This example is a bit different but solves the same problem:

Separate the callback that fixes the header in a dedicated function:

```
function FixHeader() {
    if ( $( window ).scrollTop() > 170 ) {
        $( '.header' ).addClass( 'sticky' );
    }
    else {
        $( '.header' ).removeClass( 'sticky' );
    }
}
```

Bind the callback to the scroll event:

```
$( window ).scroll( FixHeader );
```

Finally:

let the callback be invoked as the DOM is ready:

```
$( FixHeader );
```

that is a shorthand to

```
$( document ).ready( FixHeader );
```